# Splitting table over several pages

Tags: tables

I would like the table below to split over 3 pages splitting each time at the nearest \midrule how can I do this? Currently it just prints what it can until it hits the bottom of the page where it stops?

```
\begin{tabular}{clcccccccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{10}{c}{Simulation Results for n=30} \\
& & & & & & {$\sigma^2$} \\
\cline{3-10}
($\rho_1$, $\rho_2$) & Estimator & 0.0001 & 0.25 & 1 & 25 & 50 & 75 & 100 & 400 \\
\midrule
(0.99,0.99)              & HK          & 13.65     & 100    & per gram    & 13.65     & 100  & per gram    & 13.65     & 100    \\
                         & HKB         & 0.01      & 100    & each        & 0.01      & 100  & each        & 0.01      & 100 \\ 
                         & LW          & 92.50      & 100   & each        & 0.01      & 100  & each        & 0.01      & 100\\
                         & ICOMP       & 33.33      & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & S           & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & GM          & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & AM          & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & MED         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & JRR         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & URR         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & PCR         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & PCR CI      & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & R-K         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & R-K CI      & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & MCRR        & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & MCRR CI     & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & LRRE        & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & OIRE        & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & GIREI       & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & GIREII      & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
\midrule   
(0.99,0.1)               & HK          & 13.65     & 100    & per gram    & 13.65     & 100  & per gram    & 13.65     & 100    \\
                         & HKB         & 0.01      & 100    & each        & 0.01      & 100  & each        & 0.01      & 100 \\ 
                         & LW          & 92.50      & 100   & each        & 0.01      & 100  & each        & 0.01      & 100\\
                         & ICOMP       & 33.33      & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & S           & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & GM          & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & AM          & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & MED         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & JRR         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & URR         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & PCR         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & PCR CI      & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & R-K         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & R-K CI      & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & MCRR        & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & MCRR CI     & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & LRRE        & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & OIRE        & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & GIREI       & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & GIREII      & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
\midrule       
(0.9,0.9)               & HK          & 13.65     & 100    & per gram    & 13.65     & 100  & per gram    & 13.65     & 100    \\
                         & HKB         & 0.01      & 100    & each        & 0.01      & 100  & each        & 0.01      & 100 \\ 
                         & LW          & 92.50      & 100   & each        & 0.01      & 100  & each        & 0.01      & 100\\
                         & ICOMP       & 33.33      & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & S           & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & GM          & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & AM          & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & MED         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & JRR         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & URR         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & PCR         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & PCR CI      & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & R-K         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & R-K CI      & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & MCRR        & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & MCRR CI     & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & LRRE        & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & OIRE        & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & GIREI       & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & GIREII      & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
\midrule              
(0.9,0.1)               & HK          & 13.65     & 100    & per gram    & 13.65     & 100  & per gram    & 13.65     & 100    \\
                         & HKB         & 0.01      & 100    & each        & 0.01      & 100  & each        & 0.01      & 100 \\ 
                         & LW          & 92.50      & 100   & each        & 0.01      & 100  & each        & 0.01      & 100\\
                         & ICOMP       & 33.33      & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & S           & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & GM          & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & AM          & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & MED         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & JRR         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & URR         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & PCR         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & PCR CI      & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & R-K         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & R-K CI      & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & MCRR        & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & MCRR CI     & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & LRRE        & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & OIRE        & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & GIREI       & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & GIREII      & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
\midrule   
(0.7,0.3)               & HK          & 13.65     & 100    & per gram    & 13.65     & 100  & per gram    & 13.65     & 100    \\
                         & HKB         & 0.01      & 100    & each        & 0.01      & 100  & each        & 0.01      & 100 \\ 
                         & LW          & 92.50      & 100   & each        & 0.01      & 100  & each        & 0.01      & 100\\
                         & ICOMP       & 33.33      & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & S           & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & GM          & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & AM          & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & MED         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & JRR         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & URR         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & PCR         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & PCR CI      & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & R-K         & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & R-K CI      & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & MCRR        & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & MCRR CI     & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & LRRE        & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & OIRE        & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & GIREI       & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\
                         & GIREII      & 8.99       & 100   & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100  & stuffed     & 33.33      & 100\\                                                               
\bottomrule
```

\end{tabular}

Comment: Check out packages such as [`longatable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) or [`supertabular`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/supertabular).

Comment: Is that the only way?

Comment: Sorry hadn't readlized it was so easy to use longtable! It you put it a an answer I'll tick the box

Comment: There's a number of packages to typeset long tables; you can see them in CTAN: [Typesetting long tables](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/bytopic.html#setlongtables), but the ones I mentioned are the most used.

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To typeset tables spanning more than one page, you can use the [`longtable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) or the [`supertabular`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/supertabular) packages; there is also a number of other packages to this purpose, and you can see them in CTAN under [Typesetting long tables](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/bytopic.html#setlongtables).