# Automatically resize tabular to avoid it being pushed to next page

Tags: tables, scaling, adjustbox, resize

### Context

My document has one title phrase and one table containing texts. I would like to have them both on one page.

- The table's content may change (sometimes more or less 2-or-3-lines-texts cells), but there are always 2 columns and 20 rows. I have put a minimal row height of 0.5 cm for readability.
- I do **not** want to [split the table over the next page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157190/splitting-table-over-several-pages)
- But I want the text to be as big as possible.

### Attempts

If I use a smaller size, (like `\normalsize` instead of `\large`) then it fits, but the font is much smaller and actually a bit too small, whereas a large blank space is left at the bottom of the page.

So, as I want to resize (or scale?) it automatically, I thought the answer would be [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97505/shrink-table-to-fit-on-a-page-or-keep-it-as-it-is) and wanted to use the `adjustbox` package, but I can't seem to make it work the way I want. I'm a bit lost about all the keys and values meanings. Anyway, neither `\adjustbox{max width=\columnwidth}` nor `\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}` provide a solution. I couldn't find any solution using `max height` or `max totalheight`.

Also, I wonder if my problem has to do with [the more general problem of the position of a float environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020). Not sure because if the table is too large, I understand LaTeX will "push" it to the next page. But if yes, how to deal with it in this situation?

Finally I wonder if it's at all possible to achieve what I want to (moreover, using `tabular`).

### Code producing the problem

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

% Page layout 
\geometry{hmargin=1.5cm, vmargin=1.5cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\LARGE
\textbf{Mental calculation: mini-problems}
\newline \newline \large
\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth}{
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}m{14 cm}|>{\centering}m{4 cm}@{}m{0pt}@{}|}
\hline 
My golden goose laid 4 eggs each day during 9 days. How many eggs has she laid?&
 & \tabularnewline
 [0.5cm] \hline 
Mya has 40 marbles. She gives them out to 5 friends. How many marbles will get each friend?&
 & \tabularnewline
 [0.5cm] \hline 
We have 4 sheep. Our neighbours have 7 times more sheep than us. How many sheep do they have?&
 & \tabularnewline
 [0.5cm] \hline 
I will give out 72 candies to the 8 friends that I invited at my birthday's party. How many candies will receive each of my friends?&
 & \tabularnewline
 [0.5cm] \hline 
I had to fill this can with 18$~\text{L}$ of water. There was 7$~\text{L}$ left in it. How much does it contain?&
...............$~\text{L}$ & \tabularnewline
 [0.5cm] \hline 
We have loaded 64$~\text{kg}$ of flour, shared in 8 packets. How heavy is one packet?&
...............$~\text{kg}$ & \tabularnewline
 [0.5cm] \hline 
A market gardener had 72 cabbages in his vegetable garden, and harvested 54 of them last week. How many cabbages are still in the garden?&
 & \tabularnewline
 [0.5cm] \hline 
9$~\text{m}^{2}$ of this wall are already painted. 7$~\text{m}^{2}$ are still missing to have the wall completely painted. What is its area?&
...............$~\text{m}^{2}$ & \tabularnewline
 [0.5cm] \hline 
I already rode 84$~\text{km}$ out of 98$~\text{km}$. How long do I still have to go cycling?&
...............$~\text{km}$ & \tabularnewline
 [0.5cm] \hline 
Lily gets 6 £ pocket money every month. If she doesn't spend it during 7 months, how much will she spare?&
...............~£ & \tabularnewline
 [0.5cm] \hline 
Yesterday, my golden goose laid 8 eggs. That's 11 less than today. How many eggs has she laid today?&
 & \tabularnewline
 [0.5cm] \hline 
Janet bought 8 boxes of 7 pencils. How many pens did she buy?&
 & \tabularnewline
 [0.5cm] \hline 
A market gardener had 78 cabbages in his vegetable garden, and harvested 56 of them last week. How many cabbages are still in the garden?&
 & \tabularnewline
 [0.5cm] \hline 
I will give out 49 candies to the 7 friends that I invited at my birthday's party. How many candies will receive each of my friends?&
 & \tabularnewline
 [0.5cm] \hline 
Jerry has 17 marbles. Elijah has 17 marbles more than Jerry. How many marbles has Elijah?&
 & \tabularnewline
 [0.5cm] \hline 
Isabel has prepared 30 truffles splitted in 5 packets. How many truffles is there in one packet?&
 & \tabularnewline
 [0.5cm] \hline 
The gardener has planted 16 cabbages last week, and 5 cabbages more this week. How many cabbages did he plant altogether?&
 & \tabularnewline
 [0.5cm] \hline 
Our neighbours have 98 sheep. That's 70 more than us. How many sheep do we have?&
 & \tabularnewline
 [0.5cm] \hline 
Layla bought 9 pens at 7 £. How much did she pay?&
...............~£ & \tabularnewline
 [0.5cm] \hline 
My bike ride is 73$~\text{km}$ long and I already rode 36$~\text{km}$. How long do I still have to go cycling?&
...............$~\text{km}$ & \tabularnewline
 [0.5cm] \hline 
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shrinking the font size in order to make the table fit (vertically) risks making your document look like a ransom note. Have you considered using a `longtable` environment?

Comment: No, I haven't considered using a `longtable` yet, since I've read about it in questions about splitting the table over several pages. I am reluctant to change to something else than `tabular` because I need to keep some things like vertical alignment for pictures (in some cases I need to insert pictures) and between rows and I am unsure I can keep all these "settings" if I change for something else. But I'd like to know in what way could `longtable` solve this case.

Comment: The key feature that distinguishes a `longtable` environment from a `tabular` environment is that the former can handle page breaks (if needed, of course). I realize that you've stated that you do not want to split tables across pages. However, if the choice is being allowing a page split and making the table's font size absurdly small in order to fit it on a page, it may well be preferable to choose the approach that permits page breaks.

Comment: You wrote, "I wonder if my problem has to do with the more general problem of the position of a float environment." Actually, since your code doesn't figure a "float", i.e., a table or figure environment, no float-positioning issues are in play.

Comment: `max totalheight` should work (if the value is correct, you need to substract the space needed by the title). But like the other already advised I wouldn't do it. If the table must stay on one page I would use `\enlargethispage{2cm}` to allow the table to take up more place at the bottom, and if this doesn't help shorten some of the texts.

Comment: @Mico thanks for your clarification "since your code doesn't figure a "float", i.e., a table or figure": I was mixing table and tabular I think.

Comment: Actually, the biggest problem seems to be that what you consider to be a table is not a table; it's a list of items. Please do not misuse tables for lists, the result is disasterous.

Comment: @yo' I need this presentation exactly (questions in cells surrounded by borders, plus a blank cell at right to let a bit space for an answer). I have no clue how to make this using a list.

Comment: @Mico After some more research I've found `\resizebox` and `\scalebox`. For instance, `\scalebox{0.95}{begin{tabular}{...}}` produces something interesting. Why would none of the experts here tell about such boxes? Are they only a kind of dirty patch here? Is the result's quality considered too poor?

Comment: @zezollo - In my experience, the "experts here" try to provide solutions that have some kind of generality and wider applicability. Scaling a `tabular` environment by `0.95` may well "work" for one particular object -- the one *you* are interested in at the moment. However, this method is quite likely of negligible relevance to other, future readers of your posting. A general comment about scaling an object: once the scaling factor is non-trivially far from one, the result of the scaling operation tends to look plain awful, typographically speaking.

Comment: OK, I understand. Many thanks for your time and thorough explanations!

Answer (score 2):

I can understand your reluctance to split tabular material across pages. However, if the choice is between (a) allowing a page break in the middle of the tabular material and (b) shrinking the tabular material to make it fit in the available space on a page (and risking the material becoming tiny and virtually unreadable!), the former choice may well be far preferable.

Below is a solution that uses a `longtable` environment instead of the `tabular` environment. If `\normalsize` is in effect, the entire table can fit in a single page; in contrast, if `\large` or `\Large` are in effect, a page break is required. Observe the division of relative row widths, viz., 5:1, in the example code; you're free, of course, to set the relative row widths to suit your needs.

Observe further that I also advocate giving the tabular material a much more open look, mainly by getting rid of all vertical lines. Instead of text, the cells could also hold images inserted via `\includegraphics` statements. And, do consider using the `\SI` and `\si` macros of the `siunitx` package to enforce a consistent appearance of units and of number/unit pairs.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{longtable,ragged2e,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt} % provide some visual "breathing space"

% Page layout 
\geometry{margin=1.5cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\large % or: \Large, \huge, or whatever

\begingroup % localize the effect of the following \setlength instruction
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} 
\begin{longtable}{L{0.833\textwidth}R{0.167\textwidth}}

\caption{Mental calculation: Mini-problems} \label{tab:mini}\\
\multicolumn{2}{r}{Answer}\\
\hline
\endfirsthead

\caption*{Table \ref{tab:mini}, continued} \\
\multicolumn{2}{r}{Answer}\\
\hline
\endhead

\hline
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\small (Continued on the following page)}\\
\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot

My golden goose laid 4 eggs each day during 9 days. How many eggs has she laid?&\\
\hline
Mya has 40 marbles. She gives them out to 5 friends. How many marbles will each friend get?&\\
\hline
We have 4 sheep. Our neighbours have 7 times more sheep than us. How many sheep do they have?&\\
\hline
I will give out 72 candies to the 8 friends that I invited at my birthday party. How many candies will each of my friends receive?&\\
\hline
I had to fill this can with \SI{18}{\liter} of water. There was \SI{7}{\liter} left in it. How much does it contain?&
\si{\liter}\\
\hline
We have loaded \SI{64}{\kilogram} of flour, shared in 8 packets. How heavy is one packet?&
~\si{\kilogram}\\
\hline
A market gardener had 72 cabbages in his vegetable garden, and harvested 54 of them last week. How many cabbages are still in the garden?&\\
\hline
\SI{9}{\meter\squared} of this wall are already painted. \SI{7}{\meter\squared} are still missing to have the wall completely painted. What is its area?&
~\si{\meter\squared}\\
\hline
I already rode \SI{84}{\kilo\meter} out of \SI{98}{\kilo\meter}. How long do I still have to go cycling?&
~\si{\kilo\meter}\\
\hline
Lily gets 6\,£ pocket money every month. If she doesn't spend it during 7 months, how much will she spare?&
~£\\
\hline
Yesterday, my golden goose laid 8 eggs. That's 11 less than today. How many eggs has she laid today?&\\
\hline
Janet bought 8 boxes of 7 pencils. How many pens did she buy?&\\
\hline
A market gardener had 78 cabbages in his vegetable garden, and harvested 56 of them last week. How many cabbages are still in the garden?&\\
\hline
I will give out 49 candies to the 7 friends that I invited at my birthday's party. How many candies will receive each of my friends?&\\
\hline
Jerry has 17 marbles. Elijah has 17 marbles more than Jerry. How many marbles has Elijah?&\\
\hline
Isabel has prepared 30 truffles splitted in 5 packets. How many truffles are there in one packet?&\\
\hline
The gardener planted 16 cabbages last week and 5 cabbages more this week. How many cabbages did he plant altogether?&\\
\hline
Our neighbours have 98 sheep. That's 70 more than us. How many sheep do we have?&\\
\hline
Layla bought 9 pens at 7\,£. How much did she pay?&
~£\\
\hline
My bike ride is \SI{73}{\kilo\meter} long and I already rode \SI{36}{\kilo\meter}. How long do I still have to go cycling?&
~\si{\kilo\meter}\\
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, I really can't afford to split the table, it has to be on one page altogether. Yet it must be readable. Using `\large` gives a satisfying result in regards to the readability. Using `\normalsize` is a bit small. Now, I was hoping to use `\large` and rescale the whole tabular, what would require to display texts just a little bit smaller than `\large` and thought this would keep a sufficient readability.

Comment: @zezollo - Choosing `\large` brings about a 10% linear increase in font size. If you then must scale the table back down (by roughly 10%, in all likelihood) in order to make it fit on a page, you might as well use `\normalsize` immediately. Incidentally, if the table simply must fit on a table, I suggest you decrease the vertical margins a bit.

Comment: Maybe I do not estimate it very well, but if I use `\normalsize`, then the table fits into the page but there's [quite a big gap](http://pics.teotleco.org/table_normal_size.png) between its bottom and the page's bottom. So there's no way to tell LaTeX to rescale the table just a little bit, in order for it to finish to fill the page?

Comment: @zezollo - Rescaling an object affects both its width and its height, unless you do purely vertical scaling -- in which case the output will likely look seriously distorted. I really wouldn't pursue the rescaling idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your text readable (which you do 111% in a test), you really don't want to shrink it. Therefore you have to split it into two pages. Together with de-tabularizing your list, the code could look like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}


% Page layout 
\geometry{hmargin=1.5cm, vmargin=1.5cm}

\newenvironment{problems}{
    \newcommand\problem[2][]{
        \par
        \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}
        \\\nobreak\ignorespaces
        ##2
        % Borrowed from amsthm.sty
        \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999\hbox{}\nobreak\hfill\quad
        % Lower the box so that the lines of the paragraph are not disturbed
        \raisebox{-\fboxsep-\fboxrule}{\fbox{\hbox to 2cm{\strut\hfil\si{##1}}}}
        \par
    }
}{}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Mental calculation: mini-problems}

\begin{problems}
\problem{My golden goose laid 4~eggs each day during 9~days. How many eggs has she laid?}
\problem{Mya has 40~marbles. She gives them out to 5~friends. How many marbles will get each friend?}
\problem{We have 4~sheep. Our neighbours have 7~times more sheep than us. How many sheep do they have?}
\problem{I will give out 72~candies to the 8~friends that I invited at my birthday's party. How many candies will receive each of my friends?}
\problem[L]{I had to fill this can with \SI{18}{L} of water. There was \SI{7}{L} left in it. How much does it contain?}
\problem[kg]{We have loaded \SI{64}{kg} of flour, shared in 8~packets. How heavy is one packet?}
\problem{A market gardener had 72~cabbages in his vegetable garden, and harvested 54~of them last week. How many cabbages are still in the garden?}
\problem[m^2]{\SI{9}{m^2} of this wall are already painted. \SI{7}{m^2} are still missing to have the wall completely painted. What is its area?}
\problem[km]{I already rode \SI{84}{km} out of \SI{98}{km}. How long do I still have to go cycling?}
\problem[\textsterling]{Lily gets \SI{6}{\textsterling} pocket money every month. If she doesn't spend it during 7~months, how much will she spare?}
\problem{Yesterday, my golden goose laid 8~eggs. That's 11~less than today. How many eggs has she laid today?}
\problem{Janet bought 8~boxes of 7~pencils. How many pens did she buy?}
\problem{A market gardener had 78~cabbages in his vegetable garden, and harvested 56~of them last week. How many cabbages are still in the garden?}
\problem{I will give out 49~candies to the 7~friends that I invited at my birthday's party. How many candies will receive each of my friends?}
\problem{Jerry has 17~marbles. Elijah has 17~marbles more than Jerry. How many marbles has Elijah?}
\problem{Isabel has prepared 30~truffles splitted in 5~packets. How many truffles is there in one packet?}
\problem{The gardener has planted 16~cabbages last week, and 5~cabbages more this week. How many cabbages did he plant altogether?}
\problem{Our neighbours have 98~sheep. That's 70~more than us. How many sheep do we have?}
\problem[\textsterling]{Layla bought 9~pens at \SI{7}{\textsterling}. How much did she pay?}
\problem[km]{My bike ride is \SI{73}{km} long and I already rode \SI{36}{km}. How long do I still have to go cycling?}
\end{problems}

\end{document}
```

Note that I did couple more changes:

- used `siunitx`
- used `\subsection*` rather than `\textbf{\LARGE` stuff
- removed unnecessary packages
- changed `£` to `\textsterling` so that `utf8x` nor `ucs` is necessary (I'm strongly against using unicode for non-letters in `pdflatex`)
- added `~` after all the amounts

Comment: All questions must fit in one page, it can't be another way. So I certainly must play with the margins and maybe remove some questions. Now, I recognize that the presentation you suggest is indeed a very nice one. Still need to understand how it works, though.

Comment: @zezollo I'm not sure commenting the code would be very useful. You can try to understand the bits by trial and error, and if you had any question, I shall be reachable in [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative answer, which differs from my earlier answer mainly by the use of a `tabular` environment. To ensure that the tabular material *and* the header material fit on a single page while using a `\large` relative font size, it will in general be necessary to decrease the widths of the vertical margins relative to what you've specified in the posting (1.5cm).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{ragged2e,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}

% Page layout 
\geometry{hmargin=1.5cm,vmargin=0.75cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\large % or: \Large, \huge, or whatever

\textbf{Mental calculation: Mini-problems} 

\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{L{0.88\textwidth}R{0.12\textwidth}}
\multicolumn{2}{r}{Answer}\\
\hline
My golden goose laid 4 eggs each day during 9 days. How many eggs has she laid?&\\
\hline
Mya has 40 marbles. She gives them out to 5 friends. How many marbles will each friend get?&\\
\hline
We have 4 sheep. Our neighbours have 7 times more sheep than us. How many sheep do they have?&\\
\hline
I will give out 72 candies to the 8 friends that I invited at my birthday party. How many candies will each of my friends receive?&\\
\hline
I had to fill this can with \SI{18}{\liter} of water. There was \SI{7}{\liter} left in it. How much does it contain?&
\si{\liter}\\
\hline
We have loaded \SI{64}{\kilogram} of flour, shared in 8 packets. How heavy is one packet?&
~\si{\kilogram}\\
\hline
A market gardener had 72 cabbages in his vegetable garden, and harvested 54 of them last week. How many cabbages are still in the garden?&\\
\hline
\SI{9}{\meter\squared} of this wall are already painted. \SI{7}{\meter\squared} are still missing to have the wall completely painted. What is its area?&
~\si{\meter\squared}\\
\hline
I already rode \SI{84}{\kilo\meter} out of \SI{98}{\kilo\meter}. How long do I still have to go cycling?&
~\si{\kilo\meter}\\
\hline
Lily gets 6\,£ pocket money every month. If she doesn't spend it during 7 months, how much will she spare?&
~£\\
\hline
Yesterday, my golden goose laid 8 eggs. That's 11 less than today. How many eggs has she laid today?&\\
\hline
Janet bought 8 boxes of 7 pencils. How many pens did she buy?&\\
\hline
A market gardener had 78 cabbages in his vegetable garden, and harvested 56 of them last week. How many cabbages are still in the garden?&\\
\hline
I will give out 49 candies to the 7 friends that I invited to my birthday party. How many candies will receive each of my friends?&\\
\hline
Jerry has 17 marbles. Elijah has 17 marbles more than Jerry. How many marbles has Elijah?&\\
\hline
Isabel has prepared 30 truffles splitted in 5 packets. How many truffles are there in one packet?&\\
\hline
The gardener planted 16 cabbages last week and 5 cabbages more this week. How many cabbages did he plant altogether?&\\
\hline
Our neighbours have 98 sheep. That's 70 more than us. How many sheep do we have?&\\
\hline
Layla bought 9 pens at 7\,£. How much did she pay?&
~£\\
\hline
My bike ride is \SI{73}{\kilo\meter} long and I already rode \SI{36}{\kilo\meter}. How long do I still have to go cycling?&
~\si{\kilo\meter}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```